# Efficient way to add extra element to lists in Python

Tags: python, performance, list

I have list of list like:

```
[[0, 1, 2], 
 [3, 1], 
 [2, 0, 1], 
 [4, 3], 
 [1, 3, 4]]
```

list values are between 0 and 5. 
Now I want to 5+(numbers below 5 that do not exist to each list).
For example, In the first list we have 0,1,2 while we do not have 3, 4 so we want to add 5+3=8 and 5+4=9 so ultimately he new list should have 0,1,2,8,9.
The final out put should be:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 8, 9],
 [3, 1, 5, 7, 9],
 [2, 0, 1, 8, 9],
 [4, 3, 5, 6, 7],
 [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]]
```

To do so I wrote the following python code:

```
k = -1
for i in X1:
    k = k + 1
    for j in range(5, 10):        
        if j - 5 not in i:
            X[k].append(j)
```

However for large data set (list) this takes for ever. I am wondering if there is any more efficient way/suggestion I can use for this case?

Comment: Are you limited to using vanilla Python?  Can you use NumPy for example?

Comment: This smells like homework. Either way... code optimization belongs here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rayryeng I do not have to use just Python and numpy can be used. Can you provide me some guidance how numpy can be used in this case?

Comment: If possible, I would suggest to redesgin your application with Numpy and vectorized array operations in mind. This would bring a **huge** performance gain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running the `in` check (an O(n) operation for lists) for each `j-5` within the nested loop (an O(nxm) operation) slows down the performance of your code - because lookup is slow and vanilla *for* loops in Python are not cheap.

You can simply take set differences and add `5`, then extend the inner list with the result:

```
st = set(range(5)) 
for l in X1:
    l.extend(sorted([x+5 for x in st.difference(l)]))
print(X1)
```

You'll go much faster if you don't actually need to sort the new items you're appending, since the inner lists are not sorted anyway, as sorting throws in an extra O(nlogn) complexity.

Also the *for* loop in the list comprehension runs faster than a vanilla for loop, so I can argue the wall time performance of the nesting here is much better than the original.

The set difference out performs repeated`list.__contains__` while the single `list.extend` also out performs repeated `list.append`.

---

```
[[0, 1, 2, 8, 9], 
 [3, 1, 5, 7, 9], 
 [2, 0, 1, 8, 9], 
 [4, 3, 5, 6, 7], 
 [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]]
```

Comment: Shoot. I spent 5 minutes writing an explanation to my code before realising you wrote a very similar code 4 minutes ago. Well done.

Comment: BTW, I couldn't find an example for which `sorted` was needed but I might only have been lucky.

Comment: @EricDuminil I assumed they wanted the new items sorted, but then I may be wrong.

Comment: I meant to say that the elements came out sorted anyway, without `sorted`.

Comment: @EricDuminil Ah, ok. The set returned from the difference will have no ordering though, so they may actually want to sort.

Comment: Using a generator could also improve the performance as far as I know. `l.extend(x + 5 for x in st.difference(l))`. Nice approach BTW.

Comment: @slackmart No it won't. Gen exps are much slower and running the iterator to exhaustion should take more time: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L903

Answer (score 1):

> With one loop with One line solution:

Your job can be done using one loop only , Here are two method which can do your job in one loop only:

> First method using map function :

```
[large[i].extend(map(lambda x: x + 5, list({0, 1, 2, 3, 4} - set(j)))) for i,j in enumerate(large)]

print(large)
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 8, 9], [3, 1, 5, 7, 9], [2, 0, 1, 8, 9], [4, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]]
```

> Second method using numpy:

```
import numpy as np


[large[i].extend(np.asarray(list({0, 1, 2, 3, 4} - set(j))) + 5) for i,j in enumerate(large)]

print(large)
```

output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 8, 9], [3, 1, 5, 7, 9], [2, 0, 1, 8, 9], [4, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 4, 5, 7]]
```